# Collapsing of Riemannian manifolds with a group action

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, transformation-groups

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with bounded sectional curvature and $G$ a compact connected Lie group acts smoothly on $M$. Consider the fixed point set $F$, it is of course a submanifold of $M$ by the slice theorem. Let $\{F_i\}$ be the connected components of $F$. Then for each $i$, is there a sequence of Riemannian manifolds $\{M_j\},j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $M_0=M$ such that $\{M_j\}$ collapses to $F_i$ while keeping their sectional curvatures uniformly bounded?

If in general such a sequence does not exist, how about the case $G=T$? Here $T$ is a finite-dimensional torus.

Comment: Motivation?

Could you point us to a good definition of `collapsing'?

Is it true that each  Euclidean space `collapses' to a point? 
[If not, take T = S^1 acting in standard linear fashion on the plane
to get a counterexample. 

Comment: Collapsing in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense.

Comment: Do you require that all $M_j$ are diffeomorphic to $M$? If not, why not take $M_j=F_i\times $(small circle)?

Comment: Of course. The sequence $M_j$ is obtained by changing the metric on $M$.

Comment: "...Consider the fixed point set F, it is of course a submanifold of M by the slice theorem".  Note that it is really simpler than that; in geodesic coordinates at a point p of F, the fixed point set is locally the linear subspace left fixed by the linearized action at p.

Comment: I assume you give $F$ the induced metric from $M$. If the answer to your question is yes, then the curvature of $F$ is bounded from below, so in effect you hope that the fixed point set of any smooth compact group action has curvature bounded below. Why would that be true?


Comment: Or is the $G$-action assumed isometric? Then at least $F$ would have bounded curvature...

Comment: @Igor: Of course, curvature of fixed-point set of a smooth compact group need not have bounded geometry (already for $G=Z_2$). One would need some unformity assumption about the compact group action, like uniform bounds on derivatives (I am not sure how many derivatives one needs for this).  

Comment: Voted to close because the question does not make sense as stated (as explained in my and Misha's comment), and I do not see how it can be rephrased to make sense.

Comment: Is "uniformly bounded" is from below, or from both sides? If from both sides, then spheres cannot collapse to a point, and you can have a two-point set as the set of fixed points of a group acting on the sphere.



Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was noted in the comments you probably wanted to say that the action is isometric and $M_n$ is diffeomorphic to $M$ for all $n$. (Otherwise the question has no sense.)

In this case answer is NO. Consider $\mathbb S^1$ action on $\mathbb S^3$ with fixed point set $\mathbb S^1$ and note that simply connected spaces can not GH-converge to $\mathbb S^1$.

For the second part, it seems that you may only get a torus as the fixed set (?).
In this case the answer is obviously YES.